# Loading error for user defined objects from hickle(v5) file

Tags: python

I had dump dict that contains user defined object into hkl file without any errors. After that I can't load this file because of ValueError: ("Provided argument 'file_obj' does not appear to be a valid hickle file! (name 'sM' is not defined)", NameError("name 'sM' is not defined")). How can I solve this problem?

Notes: I tried to run on python v2&3, also hickle v4&5, also h5py v2&3.

Here the sample of code:

```
import hickle as hkl
results=dict()
for run_ind in range(1,runs_num+1):
#res is a user defined object that store the algorithm optimization results
        res= minimize(problem,
                algorithm,
                ('n_gen', n_gen),
                save_history=True,
                verbose=False)
        results[f"run_{run_ind}"]=res
        res= object()
hkl.dump([results,runs_num],'R1_gzip.hkl',mode='w',compression='gzip')
```

The load code:

```
import hickle as hkl
[res1,runs_num]= hkl.load("R1_gzip.hkl");
```